# When isn't a list a list?

Tags: python, list

The following code returns a list, e.g. `<class 'list'>` in python. Everything I do to access that list fails

indexing list fails,
enumerating list fails

example if I just `print(s)`

```
['0.5211', '3.1324']
```

but if I access the indices

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse-epoch.py", line 11, in <module>
    print("losses.add({}, {})".format(s[0], s[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why can't I access the elements of the list?

```
import re

with open('epoch.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content]

for line in content:
    s = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", line)
    #print(s)
    print("losses.add({}, {})".format(s[0], s[1]))
```

Comment: You need to [edit] and add the contents of `epoch.txt`, or simply the value of `content` after the 6th line. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. It seems that you have a 1-element list which for some reason you think contains 2 elements. But, since you have not given us enough information to reproduce this list, we can do no more than guess as to what the problem is.

Comment: Looks like you have a blank line in your file

Comment: Here is an example of the raw data file

Epoch [    1/   40] | d_loss: 0.8216 | g_loss: 1.8973
Epoch [    1/   40] | d_loss: 0.8570 | g_loss: 1.6021
Epoch [    1/   40] | d_loss: 1.0567 | g_loss: 2.6506
Epoch [    1/   40] | d_loss: 0.9862 | g_loss: 2.5328
Epoch [    1/   40] | d_loss: 1.0159 | g_loss: 1.3859
Epoch [    1/   40] | d_loss: 1.0116 | g_loss: 1.6647
Epoch [    1/   40] | d_loss: 0.9844 | g_loss: 1.7330

Comment: @Thediz  Your comment does not allow us to create a list, `s`, with `len(s) > 1` for which `s[1]` throws a `list index out of range` error.

Comment: @Thediz Comments don't support preformatted text. Please [edit] your question to add details.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what `print(s)` outputs again. Your issue is likely with a line where `s` does not contain a list with 2 values. If those values do not exist, then you cannot use them.

Comment: The findall value always returns a list. I checked. Python is the problem

Comment: @Thediz With "Python is the problem" are you claiming that you have discovered a bug in Python's implementation of its list data structure?

Comment: @Thediz it always returns a list yeah, but the list's length can vary.